# Find similar elements between lists

Tags: python

I want the following to just print the text if it finds the similar Text.

It gives me no Error, and no output

```
continents = ["Afrika", "Antarktis", "Asien", "Australien und Ozeanien", "Europa", "Nordamerika", "Südamerika"]
stuff = ["Asien", "Max", 101, "Monika", "China", "Simbabwe", "Antarktis"]

a = 0
b = 0

while b < len(stuff[a]):
    if continents[b] == stuff[a]:
        print(stuff[a])
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
        
    else:
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
```

Trying around for like 40 minutes

Comment: I'd recommend that you get an IDE with a debugger, like PyCharm, and learn how to use it.  You can't become a programmer without learning how to debug.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: 101 has no len() method.  you get a type error.  fix it.  what is this code trying to do?  In English, please.

Comment: The way your code works, does what it's supposed to. First understand what it's currently doing. Whiteboard will help. Look at the first iteration, what if `a` and `b` = 0? you are comparing if `Afrika` and `Asien` are the same, which is not,. Next iteration, you increment both a and b by 1. Now,  `a` and `b` = 1 but `Antarktis` and `Max` are not the same. Next iteration, `a` and `b` = 2, but `101` and `Antarktis` are not the same. Noticing a pattern there? You're comparing the value of each indexes on both list. The way it is written now, it will never find a similar text.

Comment: `a` and `b` are always incremented together, so the loop always compares the items in `stuff` and `continents` at the same location within the lists.  But, those lists do not have any items at the same location that are equal...

Answer (score 4):

Use a `set()` to find overlapping elements

```
continents = ["Afrika", "Antarktis", "Asien", "Australien und Ozeanien", "Europa", "Nordamerika", "Südamerika"]
stuff = ["Asien", "Max", 101, "Monika", "China", "Simbabwe", "Antarktis"]

print(list(set(continents) & set(stuff)))
# ['Antarktis', 'Asien']
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Answer (score 1):

getting only the matched elements

```
continents = ["Afrika", "Antarktis", "Asien", "Australien und Ozeanien", "Europa", "Nordamerika", "Südamerika"]
stuff = ["Asien", "Max", 101, "Monika", "China", "Simbabwe", "Antarktis"]

matched_elements = [elem for elem in stuff if elem in continents]
matched_elements
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue lies in the condition while b < len(stuff[a]). This condition is comparing b with the length of the element at index a in the stuff array, which is not what you intended.
To fix the issue and achieve your desired behavior of printing the text when a similar element is found, you can update your code as follows:

```
continents = ["Afrika", "Antarktis", "Asien", "Australien und Ozeanien", "Europa", "Nordamerika", "Südamerika"]
stuff = ["Asien", "Max", 101, "Monika", "China", "Simbabwe", "Antarktis"]

for item in stuff:
    if item in continents:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another perhaps more readable (and idiomatic/Pythonic) approach is to convert to sets then print the intersection.

This can be done in either of the following ways:

```
In [9]: continents = ["Afrika", "Antarktis", "Asien", "Australien und Ozeanien", "Europa", "Nordamerika", "Südamerika"]
   ...: stuff = ["Asien", "Max", 101, "Monika", "China", "Simbabwe", "Antarktis"]

In [10]: set(continents).intersection(stuff)

Out[10]: {'Antarktis', 'Asien'}
```

or, alternatively:

```
In [11]: set(continents) & set(stuff)
Out[11]: {'Antarktis', 'Asien'}
```